# Sign in to Gmail using username and password

Tags: email, gmail, imap, gmail-api, windows-8-mail-app

I use IMAP (Mailsystem.NET) and can do it, but it have problem with "Less secure app". Otherwise, Gmail API don't have problem with "less secure apps" but the login is not done directly on my application, it has to be supported by the browser.
I see Mail App on windows 8.1 can use username and password to login and don't have any problem with "less secure app" or another things. I hope someone can help me figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

The [gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) uses Oauth2 for authentication this is the browser window you mentioned.  Since 2015 this is the only way to access private user data via the gmail api.

If you want to be able to access gmail with login and password you are going to have to go directly though the [IMAP or SMTP servers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en).